# FancyBox functionality

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've implemented the futures of the FancyBox on our website which I'm designing in Asp.Net, everything was fine until the point where I've noticed that after I've opened the page using code below and make some entry's and then closing by `parent.$.fancybox.close();`.

The next time I use the same functionality to open the page the inputs on the same screen become not accessible even the rest of functionality like grid or something else is working without the issues. As soon as I'm doing full page refresh I may do again 1 time entry. Also I've noticed if I'm not using the parent.$.fancybox.close(); to close the FancyBox and using x mark to close, everything works fine no matter how many times I open the pages and close with X mark.

```
$.fancybox(
            {
                'width': '85%',
                'height': '80%',
                'autoScale': true,
                'transitionIn': 'fade',
                'transitionOut': 'fade',
                'href': Href,
                'type': 'iframe',
                'afterClose': function () {
                    __doPostBack(control, "");
                 }
              }
          );
 return false;
```

Also, when I use the following line:  `$(".Diagnosis")[0].focus();` to set the focus of the input type=text I'm getting the error : can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, I've had my share of headaches with fancybox as well, don't worry, I think this happens to everyone.

instead of using `parent.$.fancybox.close();`

see what happens if you code a function in the parent window to close the fancybox, like this:

```
function closeFancyBox(){
   $.fancybox.close();
}
```

and then call that function from the child window like this:

```
window.parent.closeFancyBox();
```

tell me what happens after that.

Also; is it safe to share the link to the page whereon the link is happenning?